# Passar variável para modal

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, variáveis

Tenho uma modal que abre ao final de uma ação (Exemplo: Desativar Usuário). Estou construindo a modal e queria que ela recebesse o texto presente em uma variável ajax. Verificar código:

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "desativarUsuario.php",
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            codigosDesativar: paraDesativar.map(function () {
                return this.cod_user
            }).get()
        },
        success: function (resposta) {
        resposta = JSON.parse(resposta);
         console.log(resposta, typeof resposta, typeof resposta[0], resposta[1]);
        if (resposta[0]) {
          var tabela = $('#tableUsuario tr');

          $.each(tabela, function(index, tr) {
            var checkbox = $(tr).find("input:checkbox");
            if ($(checkbox).is(':checked')) {
              $(tr).find(".status").text("Inativo");
              $(tr).find(".status").css("color", "#BD362F");
              $(tr).find(".inativo").addClass('hide');
              $(tr).find(".ativo").removeClass('hide');
            } 
          });
        }
        alert(resposta[1]);
    }
    });
```

A variavel `resposta` retorna: `Array [ true, "Usuário foi desativado com Sucesso!" ]`

Como passar para dentro da modal a baixo esta mensagem "Usuário foi desativado com Sucesso!":

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Confirmation</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>AQUI QUERIA A MENSAGEM@!!!!!!</p>
                <p class="text-warning"><small>If you don't save, your changes will be lost.</small></p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode adicionar no seu success isso

```
$(".modal-body p").html("Usuário foi desativado com Sucesso!");
```

usando seu array

```
 $(".modal-body p").html(resposta[1]);
```

Comment: Só uma outra dúvida relacionada:

    `if($ativar==2){<script>$(".modal-body p").html("Selecione pelo menos um usuário que deseja desativar!");
   $(document).ready(function(){
              $("#modalMsgAviso").modal('show');
            });</script>}`

informa ter erro faltando '<'. O que pode ser?

Comment: Há sim, pode falar que estou aqui?

Comment: Por que você usou aquela tag <script> dentro do if ? Seu código já deve estar dentro de uma, você não precisa colocar outra.

Comment: Editei o comntário @vcrzy

Comment: Opa.. Deu certo?

Comment: Meu código não está dentro de uma tag script. Está dentro de um PHP. Devo tirar mesmo assim?

Comment: Entendi, faz o seguinte. Pega o $(".modal-body p").html("Selecione pelo menos um usuário que deseja desativar!"); e coloca dentro do document ready também. Ai depois tu faz um echo em tudo. Por exemplo: if($ativar==2){ echo '<script>seu código aqui</script>'; Se não der certo, sugiro abrir uma outra pergunta ou colocar isso online, sendo assim posso ver e te ajudar a resolver. Vou almoçar e depois estamos ai, valeu

Comment: Deu certo cara. Obrigado :D

Comment: hahahaha por nada. abras